# Moving and Copying Columns Between Tables in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using the latest version of MySQL Workbench 5.2.40.

In the EER Diagram, is there a way to copy/paste columns between tables, as well as move columns from one table to another using drag and drop?

I don't see any any such feature now. If this is the case, it would be difficult to do preliminary design using Workbench considering that it will be tedious to modify or correct your designs later on. I might as well go straight to the physical design using PhpMyAdmin since I can copy-paste portions of SQL statements when altering tables.

Any work-around modifying columns in Workbench?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of MySQL Workbench is 6.0.7 and yes, you can copy and paste column definitions using the context menu in the table editor (not directly in the diagram). Just open the tables you want to edit. Usually, the editor is reused if an object of the same type is opened for editing, but there's an entry in the  context menu of the objects that allows to open the object in a new tab. This way you can have two table editors on 2 tabs and can easily switch back and forth for copying e.g. column definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. I hope you can clarify further.  I installed this version and was able to create two sample tables. http://imgur.com/jEVIYf6. Does this mean that I have to switch back and forth and manually recreate the columns between tables?

Comment: If you mean switch back and forth between the 2 table editors then yes. That's the way to do it. But since this is all close together, it should not be a nuisance.

Comment: Shucks. I'm now imagining the effort required splitting or merging tables, especially during the early stages where the table schema is still being deliberated. I wish Oracle would put up the necessary resources to improve this tool. Thanks for your inputs Mike!

Comment: You are constantly copying columns between tables? That's surprising, but consider also table templates which give you the opportunity to define certain table structures which you can reuse to ease that work.

Answer (score 0):

I handle these cases this way :

- do the modifications on the physical tables (using pma, or the "schema editor" tab of mwb, or the command-line)
- then synchronize database and model

In fact, I'd find useful to be able to manipulate the schema directly in SQL; GUI would then (as pma is) simply be a more convenient way to to some actions ('Create a table' would generate, then execute, an SQL 'CREATE TABLE' statement)
But it would probably mean a redesign from scratch - at least for the way the schema is stored.